# docker container run -it cypress/included:8.6.0 throws ERROR: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs' in '/cypress/cypress/support'

Tags: linux, docker, cypress

**Environment:**

```
Linux VM: Ubuntu Server 18.04. LTS
```

What am I trying to achieve?

A) To run cypress inside a container, to improve our testing capabilities

Which image am I using?

```
cypress/included:8.6.0
```

What command am I using?

```
sudo docker run -d -it -v $PWD:/UI_Test_Automation -w ~/UI_Test_Automation cypress/included:8.6.0 /bin/bash
```

Which was the result?

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/commands.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs' in '/cypress/cypress/support'
resolve 'dayjs' in '/cypress/cypress/support'
  Parsed request is a module
  No description file found
  Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths: or is not a directory
[/cypress/cypress/support/package.json]
[/cypress/cypress/support/node_modules]
[/cypress/cypress/node_modules]
[/cypress/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
 @ ./cypress/support/commands.js 17:4-20
 @ ./cypress/support/index.js

    at handle (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:176:23)
    at finalCallback (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at /root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:306:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:22
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
    at /root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:298:10
    at /root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:482:27
    at /root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)

This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

- A missing file or dependency
- A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.
```

Base on the above error log, I have the feeling requires **dayjs**, but not sure how to solve it:

1. Should I install the *dayjs* component inside the container? then how?
2. Is there another way to make sure the container isn't missing the *dayjs* library to allow the run correctly the *cypress*?

Thanks in advance to the StackOverflow community for all that can be provided

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass xwindows info and start dbus service

```
docker container run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $PWD:/cypress -w /cypress -e DISPLAY -it --entrypoint bash cypress/included:8.6.0

root@1592a34bdcca:/cypress# service dbus start
[ ok ] Starting system message bus: dbus.
root@1592a34bdcca:/cypress# cypress run
```

Try not to use `sudo` when running docker.

Comment: Hi @Philippe, thanks for taking to time to answer,

Did perform above steps and then *run* throws the next error, see below, I have the impression I need to manage how to install inside the container *npm* because complaints about missing *dayjs*

Comment: #### Log message  1:
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/commands.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs' in '/cypress/cypress/support'
resolve 'dayjs' in '/cypress/cypress/support'
  Parsed request is a module
  No description file found
  Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths: or is not a directory
[/cypress/cypress/support/package.json]
[/cypress/cypress/support/node_modules]
[/cypress/cypress/node_modules]
[/cypress/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
 @ ./cypress/support/commands.js 17:4-20
 @ ./cypress/support/index.js

Comment: #### Log message 2:
 at handle (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:176:23)
    at finalCallback (/root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at /root/.cache/Cypress/8.6.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:306:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create